# @IdempotentReceiver annotation does not work

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I am trying to use the @IdempotentReceiver annotation as mentioned in Spring Integration 4.1.2 reference guide with the following Java Config example (modified to include my logic):

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IdempotentReceiverConfig {

    public static class MyPayload {
        public String transactionId;
        public String data;

        public MyPayload(final String transactionId, final String data) {
            this.transactionId = transactionId;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public static class MyTransformer {
        public MyPayload process(final MyPayload input) {
            MyPayload newPayload = new MyPayload(input.transactionId, input.data.toUpperCase());
            return newPayload;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public IdempotentReceiverInterceptor idempotentReceiverInterceptor() {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("payload.transactionId");
        MetadataStoreSelector selector = new MetadataStoreSelector(new ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor<String>(exp));
        IdempotentReceiverInterceptor interceptor = new IdempotentReceiverInterceptor(selector);
        interceptor.setDiscardChannel(discardChannel());
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel1")
    @IdempotentReceiver("idempotentReceiverInterceptor")
    public MessageHandler myService1() {
        ServiceActivatingHandler handler = new ServiceActivatingHandler(new MyTransformer(), "process");
        handler.setOutputChannel(outputChannel());
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel2", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
    @IdempotentReceiver("idempotentReceiverInterceptor")
    public Transformer myService2() {
        return new MethodInvokingTransformer(new MyTransformer(), "process");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inputChannel1() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inputChannel2() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel discardChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outputChannel")
    public LoggingHandler outputLoggingHandler() {
        LoggingHandler handler = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
        handler.setLoggerName("Success.LoggingHandler");
        handler.setExpression("'Message passed: ' + payload.data");
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "discardChannel")
    public LoggingHandler discardLoggingHandler() {
        LoggingHandler handler = new LoggingHandler("WARN");
        handler.setLoggerName("Fail.LoggingHandler");
        handler.setExpression("'Message discarded: ' + payload.data");
        return handler;
    }
}
```

However, it seems that the IdempotentReceiverInterceptor is not applied to the endpoint if I use a ServiceActivatingHandler (inputChannel1). If I change to XML configuration or use a Transformer (inputChannel2), the program works fine.

I test the above by sending two messages to both inputChannel1 and inputChannel2:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(IdempotentReceiverConfig.class);
MessageChannel channel;
MyPayload payload = new MyPayload("1234", "testing");

channel = (MessageChannel) ctx.getBean("inputChannel1");
channel.send(new GenericMessage<MyPayload>(payload));
channel.send(new GenericMessage<MyPayload>(payload));

channel = (MessageChannel) ctx.getBean("inputChannel2");
channel.send(new GenericMessage<MyPayload>(payload));
channel.send(new GenericMessage<MyPayload>(payload));
```

and the result is:

```
[main] [LoggingHandler] INFO   - Message passed: TESTING
[main] [LoggingHandler] INFO   - Message passed: TESTING

[main] [LoggingHandler] INFO   - Message passed: TESTING
[main] [LoggingHandler] WARN   - Message discarded: testing
```

so I can confirm the messages still go to the MessageHandler for the inputChannel1 case.

After some study, I found that Spring's AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(...) method has the following logic to handle IdempotentReceiver annotation:

```
if (AnnotatedElementUtils.isAnnotated(method, IdempotentReceiver.class.getName())   && !AnnotatedElementUtils.isAnnotated(method, Bean.class.getName())) {
...
}
```

which seems to me it does not allow both @Bean and @IdempotentReceiver at the same time.

Is there any working sample of @IdempotentReceiver? Do I miss anything?

EDITED: updated the question with a complete configuration. The myService1() will return a ServiceActivatingHandler which invokes a POJO transformer, and myService2() uses a Transformer. The transformer just performs a simple toUpperCase() operation on the payload.data field, so we can see if it has been invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@IdempotentReceiver` on the `@Bean` level is parsed by the `IdempotentReceiverAutoProxyCreatorInitializer`.

We have a test-case on the matter - `IdempotentReceiverIntegrationTests`.

From other side: how do you want to be sure that it works as expected?

Show, please, your `myService()` content. For any `AbstractMessageProducingHandler` the `outputChannel` must be specified as the setter on that `AbstractMessageProducingHandler` implementation. Not like `outputChannel` attribute of the `@ServiceActivator`.

I'll back to you when I'll do some testing on the matter.

**UPDATE**

My test-case confirms that everything works well:

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputService")
    @IdempotentReceiver("idempotentReceiverInterceptor")
    public MessageHandler messageHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                if (message.getHeaders().containsKey(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.DUPLICATE_MESSAGE)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate message");
                }
            }

        };

    }
```

And I do this:

```
Message<String> message = new GenericMessage<String>("bar");
this.inputService.send(message);
this.inputService.send(message);
```

If the `idempotentReceiverInterceptor` hasn't been applied the second `send` passes, but it doesn't. At least for me.

Can you minimize your config and test to allow me to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: I have updated the question with my logic. The tradeServiceStub() is just another @Bean method to return a POJO transformer object.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If I follow the test-case and change myService() to return a Transformer, the program works as expected. I just don't understand what is wrong with my original logic returning a ServiceActivatingHandler...

Comment: 1. Have you tried to move `output` from the `@ServiceActivator` to the setter of `ServiceActivatingHandler`? 2. Confirm for me, please, that your `TradeServiceStub` accepts all your messages meaning `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` hasn't been appliend. 3. I guess it is really a bug if the `@Bean` result is `MessageHandler`. It has a bit different `id` so, the `IdempotentReceiverAutoProxyCreatorInitializer` doesn't find the bean to apply Advice. Well, it is a bug! Feel free to raise a JIRA issue!

Comment: I have updated the question with a minimized config and test result. In the code I have set the outputChannel explicitly on ServiceActivatingHandler but the IdempotentReceiverInterceptor still hasn't been applied.